# Como deixar uma tabela de checkboxes (Tabela de níveis de acesso) responsiva?

Tags: html, css, layout-responsivo, table, checkbox

Não sei se alguém já se deparou com esse tipo de estrutura. Mas é o seguinte, preciso deixar essa tabela da imagem abaixo responsiva. Alguém ja viu algo, sabe como, ou tem alguma idéia de como implementar, ou algum outro modo mas respeitando a lógica?

[image: tabela de niveis de acesso com checkboxes]

[DEMO JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2p9pkyht/)

Comment: O máximo que consigo pensar é esconder os header das colunas conforme a largura vai reduzindo, até ficar sem header, e as colunas na largura mínima pra caber o checkbox. Mesmo assim, tem um limite mínimo de largura da tabela toda...

Comment: Exatamente @bfavaretto e também acho que ficaria meio confuso para o usuário.

Comment: Uma outra coisa que poderia ser feito, seria uma sub-tabela

Comment: como assim @KaduAmaral? Tem algum exemplo ai?

Comment: Existe um plugin chamado [Footable](http://fooplugins.com/footable-demos/)

Comment: Entendi @KaduAmaral, estou usando um parecido com esse, o DataTables que faz a mesma coisa desse Footable. Mas quero fazer algo que fique mais visível possível, não quero esconder como no exemplo.

Comment: Hmm, então tu pode fazer tipo um overflow, estilo o do **[Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive)**. Consegue simular essa tabela no JSFiddle pra gente trabalhar nela?

Comment: Você poderia mudar o layout, deixando por exemplo [Grupo] e deixar os checkbox abaixo do [Grupo], tipo um titulo, assim você consegue ter algo responsive

Comment: Não entendi muito bem o que quiz dizer @Rod, tem algum exemplo?

Comment: @KaduAmaral, adicionei o link para o Fiddle na pergunta.

Comment: O que eu tinha sugerido era isso **[JSFiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/2p9pkyht/1/)**

Comment: Quando estive diante do mesmo problema (no meu caso não havia nada fixo, até as funcionalidades possíveis eram dinâmicas) eu achei melhor usar um `accordion`. Cada `panel` representava um grupo, ficou simples de fazer ficar responsivo. Sem querer sair do escopo da sua pergunta...

Comment: Então @KaduAmaral, essa é a minha primeira opção se eu não encontrar nada melhor. Ja tinha pensado em algo assim.

Comment: Entendi @Cold, mas acho que pra mim num iria ficar bom :/

Comment: Não sei como está seu sistema, mas também poderia colocar uma página única para alterar as permissões de um grupo, em vez de uma tabela.

Comment: Sim, pensei em algo mais ou menos assim. Mas ao invés de pagina, abrir um Lightbox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O conceito de "responsivo" quando falamos em dados tabulares, e de certa forma quando falamos sobre quaisquer elementos, tem limitações que se prendem com a usabilidade.

No caso particular da tua tabela, podem ser utilizadas algumas técnicas para adaptar a mesma a dispositivos mais pequenos, mas a partir de um certo ponto, as barras de deslocamento desempenham uma tarefa crucial para manter a leitura e usabilidade da tabela.

**Nota:** Dado que estás a fazer uso do Bootstrap, no exemplo em baixo faz-se uso de algumas [classes de CSS auxiliares presentes na Framework](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>.

### Soluções aplicadas:

1. Em tela de largura muito reduzida, usamos *icon* ao invés de texto;
2. O tamanho do texto vai sendo reduzido ou aumentado consoante o tamanho da tela;
3. Fazendo uso de classes auxiliares presentes no Bootstrap, apresenta-se o texto ou o *icon* consoante a largura da tela;
4. Quando o *icon* está em uso, o texto está presente como título do mesmo para permitir ao utilizador uma correta identificação do *icon*;
5. Tabela com largura mínima para garantir a leitura e usabilidade da mesma. As barras de deslocamento são usadas abaixo dessa largura para complementar a navegação.

### HTML

Com a classe `visible-xs`, conseguimos garantir que determinado elemento só aparece em telas muito reduzidas tipo telemóvel ou menores.

Com a classe `hidden-xs`, conseguimos garantir que o texto é escondido quando o icon está visivel.

```html
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil visible-xs" title="Editar"></span>
<span class="hidden-xs">Editar</span>
<input type="checkbox"/>
```

### CSS

Fazendo uso de [*media queries*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>, conseguimos manipular as propriedades CSS de cada elemento de forma a que os mesmos se adaptem ao tamanho da tela.

Neste caso estamos a manipular o tamanho do texto até um determinado ponto. Após isso, conforme explicado em cima, o mesmo deixa de aparecer e é apresentado um icon que o representa:

```
/* Landscape phones and smaller */
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    table.cf thead th{
        font-size:0.6em;
    }
}

/* Landscape phones and portrait tablets */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    table.cf thead th{
        font-size:0.6em;
    }
}

/* Portrait tablets and small desktops */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    table.cf thead th{
        font-size:0.6em;
    }
}

/* Portrait tablets and medium desktops */
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
    table.cf thead th{
        font-size:0.8em;
    }
}

/* Large desktops and laptops */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {

}
```

### Resultado

Com este exemplo prático a tabela pode ser lida num dispositivo com 360px largura até ao mais largo dos ecrãs:

[**Exemplo a funcionar no JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/pjt9x4s6/)

**Nota:** O título "editar" aparece porque o rato está por cima do *icon* "Editar".

[image: Captura de tela 360px largura]

---

A baixo dos 360 pixeis, a sugestão é o uso de barras de deslocamento onde a tabela fica com uma largura fixa de `360px` e as barras de deslocamento facultam a navegação auxiliar.

Comment: Muito bom @Zuul! Obrigado!